# VBA: Counting time stamps

Tags: vba, excel

Currently have a macro that attempts to count for identical time stamps.

As you'll see in the code below, I am converting the time stamp to a value then using COUNTIFS(), counting for identical time stamps based off of that value.

Then, if it counts 2 or more of the same stamp, that associate name will appear in a list in a new sheet (also produces a list of associates that are missing time stamps altogether).

Now, what I would really like to do is see if I can count based on time stamps that are within two minutes of each other. I THINK I should get rid of that whole value conversion and find a way to count for the actual time stamps, but that is exactly what brings me here as I'm not quite sure how to approach it!

Thank you all in advance. Cheers.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm working with:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLBd9.png]

```
    'Convert date to value

For x = 2 To lastrow

    Cells(x, 22) = "=LEFT((VALUE(RC[-4])),9)"

Next

Range("V:V").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Count for duplicate time stamps


For x = 2 To lastrow

    Cells(x, 23) = "=COUNTIFS(RC[-1]:R[918]C[-1],RC[-1],RC[-11]:R[918]C[-11], RC[-11])"

Next

Range("W:W").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'If same time stamp is seen 2 or more times for a given associate, their name will appear in column X
'If an associate is missing timestamps altogether, their name will appear in column Y

For x = 2 To lastrow

    If Cells(x, 18) = "" Then Cells(x, 25) = Cells(x, 12)
    If Cells(x, 23) >= 2 And Cells(x, 18) <> "" Then Cells(x, 24) = Cells(x, 12)

Next

Columns("X:X").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$X$1:$X$920").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
Columns("Y:Y").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$Y$1:$Y$920").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: Does it matter if JohnDoe/JaneDoe shows up on the other sheet more than once?

Comment: Apologies - post updated to reflect duplicate removal

Answer (score 0):

2/1440 is decimal value for two minutes ... time in excel is number ... you can make condition with +- 2/1440

Comment: While you are certainly right. I am not quite sure how that makes it any easier. If I have a "chain" of timestamps (all of which are within a two minute time frame) then you'd have to identify the first of them and sort all of the others so realize that such a chain exists. For example: `09:03`, `09:11`, `09:09`, `09:05`, `09;07`. Once you sort this sample you come to realize that there is a two minute timestamp chain. If I understand the OP correctly then this chain should be identified and grouped together. How it your *comment* helping cope with that?

Answer (score 0):

So the thing youre after is a way to compare dates. THere is a really awesome function called DateDiff

```
 DateDif( interval, date1, date2, [firstdayofweek], [firstweekofyear] )

 borrowed from https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php
```

To be able to use this efficiently you may have to rewrite your loop a little bit. This could get stupid easy b/c youre removing duplicates at the end so no need to get fancy with your loop structure. What I would do is something like this. I iused arrays but you can just swipe the DateDiff part if you'd like. This is untested as well. I think itll suite your needs though.

```
Dim aRR As Variant
aRR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("V2:W300")
Dim empName As String
Dim timeStamp As Date

Dim i As Integer

For i = LBound(aRR, 1) To UBound(aRR, 1)
    empName = aRR(i, 0)
    timeStamp = aRR(i, 1)
    For j = LBound(aRR, 1) To UBound(aRR, 1)
        If aRR(j, 0) <> aRR(i, 0) Then
            If aRR(i, 0) = aRR(j, 0) And (aRR(i, 1) = aRR(j, 1) Or DateDiff("n", aRR(i, 1), aRR(j, 1)) <= 2) Then
                'logic used for moving names over
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Because you are not familiar with arrays I guess Ill explain them for you. The arrays we are working are two dimensional arrays. Think of it like a worksheets. When you reference array points you generally use ArrayName(row, columns). When you use Lbound or UBound (upper versus lower bound) you have to declare which dimension of the array you want to scan through(1 being the first dimension, or 0, and so on). In  this particular instance I only looped through the first dimension instead of the entire array b/c we really only need to work with employee Names (EmpName) as referencing the date/time stamp is easiest by saying aRR(i, 1) which is to be read as "the current point in the array (loop i) column 1.

Comment: Thanks for the response Doug. As I am not too familiar with using arrays, please bare with me. For empName and timeStamp. Where you declare them equal to aRR(i, 0) and aRR(j, 1) respectively. If I am using columns A and B, would it be correct in defining them as aRR(i, 1) and aRR(j, 2)? and adjusting the rest of the code accordingly?  Also, let's pretend I'm not adding a new sheet for now and just working with the two columns. Where the "moving names over" logic goes, would something such as "Then cells(x,3) = empName" suffice in this example the same way I did it in my initial attempt? Thanks

Comment: I guess I ought to explain some stuff. Ill edit my answer

Comment: Also just because I used an array doesnt mean you have to. The point was to use DateDiff in your code. I only used arrays b/c i find that theyre super fast and easier to work with. If you wanted to retool your code to work in an array instead of the worksheet, it can be easily done but you'd be basically rewriting the whole thing. You can easily just adjust your code to use datediff.

Comment: I got you. Thanks for elaborating on how the array works. I like the idea of the array as I think it's a much smoother way of approaching this kind of problem than what I was attempting in the OP. What the array would do (I'd imagine) is get rid of the need to convert values/do the COUNTIFS/the proceeding FOR loop. Still uncertain as to how I'd emulate the logic involved in populating a list of the relevant names within the array. Will continue to research this on my own but obviously any further help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, in the section "Code to move stuff goes here" you could just statically put that employees name on the next line, OR you could use another array and fill that one with your names to dump to sheet at the end of the procedure. The loop's i used circumvents the countif's b/c the IF statements are literally checking if name equals name and time stamp equals timestamp or if datediff is <= or equal to 2. Basically, if the empName/timeStamp combo is found any where else it is >= 2

Comment: If you provide a sample of the worksheet youre using i can tailor something more specific instead of trying to guess. Like I understand that youre using a variety of different columns but having a more defined approach would help

Comment: Got it. Is there a way for me to link you to an excel document? For my purposes, the image in OP is what I am dealing with directly. Just Column A which contains Employee Names and Column B that contains the time stamps.

Comment: @Charles you can add it to OP